# eclipse-rcp problem : context menu added by viewerContribution not work

Tags: eclipse-rcp

```
 <extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
    <viewerContribution
          id="com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.ConnectionsViewPopupContribution"
          targetID="com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.views.ConnectionsView">
       <action
             class="com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.actions.OpenConnectionAction"
             id="com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.actions.OpenConnectionAction"
             label="打开"
             menubarPath="additions">
       </action>
    </viewerContribution>
 </extension>
```

but when I open the com.amarsoft.sysconfig.plugin.views.ConnectionsView view right click ,nothing happened...

I will edit my post to add any information needed , as now I dont know what may cause this problem.

Comment: How did you create and then register your context menu?

Comment: @Paul Do you mean I need to add some code in my ConnectionsView class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` or `org.eclipse.ui.menus` (preferred) to be able to contribute to a view context menu, that view must register the menu with the framework, usually in `createPartControl(Composite)`.  ex:

```
MenuManager contextManager = new MenuManager();
contextManager.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
Menu contextMenu = contextManager.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
viewer.getControl().setMenu(contextMenu);
getSite().registerContextMenu(contextManager, viewer);
```

You can create a sample plugin and generate the view template, and it will provide an example of hooking up to a `TreeViewer`.  If you don't use JFace viewers, then you need to provide an implementation of `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're targeting Eclipse 3.3 or before, consider moving to the new extension points. See [this blog entry](http://tonnymadsen.blogspot.dk/2007/06/translating-objectcontributions-into.html) for more information...

**UPDATED_** link