# Steps needed to add context menu to eclipse outline view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I would like to add a context menu to the Eclipse standard Outline View. Just adding a menuContribution with url

```
popup:org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline
```

did not work, so I guess I need to create the context menu first. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340109/eclipse-rcp-problem-context-menu-added-by-viewercontribution-not-work), I read that the menu has to be created in the view's createPartControl() method. But when adding a context menu to another view like the Outline View, where do I put this code?

Comment: Each editor contributes a separate page to the outline view and each page has its own context menu. So you need to know which editor you want to contribute too and what id it uses for its context menu.

Comment: I created a context menu with a MenuManager and added it to the ContentOutlinePage's control. However, the menu is displayed as a normal menu (the one that expands when I click on the small triangle), not as a context menu inside the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a context menu for a view use something like:

```java
MenuManager contextMenu = new MenuManager();

Control control = viewer.getControl();
Menu menu = contextMenu.createContextMenu(control);
control.setMenu(menu);

getSite().registerContextMenu("menu id", contextMenu, viewer);
```

where `viewer` is the outline tree viewer.

The final `registerContextMenu` call means that you can contribute to this menu using the menu id you specify.

Comment: If I don't have a viewer, can I just call setMenu(menu) on the control that is returned in getControl()?

Comment: The context menu can be on any control, but the registerContextMenu third parameter must be something that implements `ISelectionProvider` so you might have to write a simple selection provider.

Comment: And menuId:org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline is the right locationURI to use in my plugin.xml?

Comment: No it is the id you specify on the registerContextMenu

Comment: I don't know for sure, probably not.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the comment because I it found out myself :) I was surprised it actually does work.

Comment: Can you outline exactly what needs to go in the plugin.xml?  There are about 17 ways to create menus in Eclipse and I'm not entirely sure which one this expects.

Answer (score 0):

This `menuContribution` `locationURI` worked for me:

`popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.outline`